# Why is setting the expiry time ineffective in Redis

Tags: redis

Now i use redispipeline to set key to redis ,and set key timeout.After running codes and timeout,and the keys are still in redis?It seemed doesn't work.Is there sth wrong with my code.
X[1] is dict,such as dict["a"]=b dict["c"]=d

```
        redis_pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host = redis_ip, port = redis_port, decode_responses = False)
        redis_connection = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool = redis_pool)
        redis_pipeline = redis_connection.pipeline(transaction = False)
        sync_count = 0
        for x in iterator:
            key = suffix + x[0]
            #value = str(x['tagid'])+"\t"+x['tag_name']
            value = x[1]
            redis_pipeline.hmset(key,  value)
            redis_pipeline.expire(key,60)
            sync_count += 1
            if (sync_count % 100 == 0):
                result = redis_pipeline.execute()
                print (result)
                time.sleep(0.001)
                break
            if sync_count == 10000:
                break
        redis_pipeline.execute()
```

Comment: Can you include the printed output? Note hmset requires a key and then field-value pairs. What is x[1] type?

Comment: I have updated the x[1].X[1] is dict. The printed result is True.It seemd execute successful